# Resizing Image Buttons and Image Views on a XML Page

Tags: java, android, xml

So I have this XML layout page, but when i put it on a bigger screen nothing resizes, i was wondering how this would be done. Can it be done through the XML or Java, or both?

This is my layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainPage"
android:background="@drawable/appbackground3"
android:id="@+id/HomeLayout">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/PlayBtn"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton2"
    android:src="@drawable/playbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/TitleImg"
    android:background="@drawable/title"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is because you are already setting the height and width of the images. What do you expect the system will do? I would rather use wrap_content, match_parent, Fill_parent depending what you want the UI to look like. That way your app will behave differently in every layout and screen sizes. I highly recommend you look into [fragments](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/basics/fragments/index.html), as they will give you much more flexibility.

Comment: @Raj, if my answer solved your problem please consider accepting it as an answer.